# Segmentation Fault on raspbian stretch

Tags: raspbian-stretch

I have a few SD cards that work fine on the Raspberry pi 3.. its the new raspbian stretch.

Whenever I transfer it to the raspberry pi zero W. I get segmentation fault when trying to run various programs.

Comment: are you certain that the RPi3 and RPi Zero are interchangeable?

Comment: An example of "various programs" together with the exact error message would help.

Comment: @jsotola  3b+ is 64 bit, Zero 32 bit.  Any distro that has anything specific for the 3b+, has no chance of running or the Zero.

Comment: Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to track the cause by using `strace` on both systems and compare the results. E.g. `strace -f ./mybinary`. This gives a lot of output, which you might want to redirect to a file, as well as to stdout: `strace -f ./mybinary 2>&1 | tee /tmp/strace.txt`.

Mostly it can be helpful to grep on `open` to find the files that might cause the problem (`grep open /tmp/strace.txt`).

If `strace` is not on your system yet, install it via `sudo apt install strace`.